# Help creating selective IF statement

Tags: weblogic

I have this code that sends a text message to your mobile phone...

```
$text = fopen("../data/textmembers/registry.txt","r") or die("couldent open file");

while (!feof($text)) {
$name = fgets($text);
$number = fgets($text);
$carrier = fgets($text);
$date = fgets($text);
$line = fgets($text);


$content = $_POST['message']; 

$message .= $content; 
$message .= "\n";
$number = trim($number);




mail($number . "@vtext.com", "SGA Event Alert", $message, "SGA"); 
Header("Location: mailconf.php");
```

everything works fine.. Here is my question, if you look at where I have "@vtext.com"
as you may or may not know, each carrier has its own extension, verizon is @vtext.com, at&t is @txt.att.net. I need to take the feed from "$carrier" decide what carrier it is, and then assign the extension to it... 
I thought an ifelse would work, but I am not good with if statements... 
the user's choices are

Verizon = 1234567890@vtext.com
AT&T = 1234567890@txt.att.net
T-mobile = @tmomail.net
Nextel = @messaging.nextel.com

thanks guys!!

Comment: If you're not good with if statements, you really need to learn them.  Here's an overview: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/ifelse.php.  It's an absolute basic of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$carriers = array(
  "verizon"  => "vtext.com",
  "at&t"     => "txt.att.net",
  "t-mobile" => "tmomail.net",
  "nextel"   => "messaging.nextel.com"
);
```

Then, you get that value by looking up the key:

```
print $carriers[strtolower($carrier)];
```

If `$carrier` is "Nextel," "messaging.nextel.com" will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better than using an `if` statement would be using a `switch` statement.

Have a look at the [section](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) of the PHP [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) that deals with the `switch` statement.